# How exactly do I tell if "A xxx of" is plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, singular

I looked up a few grammar-teaching websites (in Chinese language). The website says many people do not use the phrase "A xxx of" correctly because they do not identify the subject of the phrase correctly.

The website says phrases like "A range of; A high percentage of" is singular, while "a number of; a group of; a couple of; a total of" is plural.

Therefore according to the website, the correct sentences should be as follows.

> A wide range of courses ***is*** available. ("A wide range" is the subject)
>
> A high percentage of peptides that are made of amino acids ***is*** present
>   in the sample. ("A high percentage" is the subject)
>
> A number/ group/ couple of people ***were*** killed in the earthquake.("people" is the subject )
>
> A total of 230 employees ***were*** laid off. ("employees" is the subject)

I don't get the pattern here. All of this looks (or should I use "look"?) arbitrary to me. In fact I thought this phrase is supposed to be arbitrary and whether the phrase is plural or singular should depend on the the person's own judgment.

How do I identify the correct subject in the "A xxx of" phrase?

Comment: "Courses" is the subject of number one. And "peptides" is the subject of number two. What are available? Courses. What are present in the sample? Peptides.

Comment: Look into British English. You'll find that the meanings change based on whether the noun is treated as a singular collective vs multiple, individual parts. American teachers would probably day that the fourth sentence is very much wrong.

Comment: You chose "this" so you need "all of this looks"; you decided that "all" would be singular. Alternately you could just as well have said "all of these look". It seems to be a special case where the prepositional object does influence the pronoun before it. Yeah, it's probably not consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on context, rather than fitting a specific pattern.

> A wide range of courses **is** available. ("A wide range" is the subject)

Here, *range* is a singular noun, in context it is unique. (One range will differ from another range.)

> A high percentage of peptides that are made of amino acids **are** present in the sample. ("A high percentage" is the subject)

Here, logically a *high percentage* of (a group of) peptides would be more than one, so it is plural.

> A number/group/couple of people **were** killed in the earthquake.("people" is the subject)

Here, *number/group/couple* refers to a quantity (of people) greater than 1, so it is plural.

> A total of 230 employees **were** laid off. ("employees" is the subject)

Here, *total* refers to 230, so it is plural.